# How to bcc another recipient on an Amazon Cognito verification email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

For legal reasons I need to BCC someone on my Cognito verification emails when someone signs up on my website. Is there a way to configure this in Amazon SES or Cognito? I have searched through the settings on both of the services and searched google but I haven't been able to find anything. I am wondering if maybe I should use SNS to trigger a welcome email with the compliance information *after* the user verifies their email, though I am still not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a Cognito [custom email sender](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html) Lambda function. There's an example of that function using NodeJS at the above link. Having gone through this myself I would point out that it can only be done using NodeJS or Java due to the specific AWS encryption SDK needed to decode the email body in your Lambda function.

Inside that example Lambda function you can see the different event triggers the function has to handle. In the `CustomEmailSender_SignUp` trigger handler you would add your BCC when you send the email.

You would need to use the AWS SDK inside that code to send the emails using SES.